# Include Path is not recognized in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, include, include-path

I've been reading at almost every question related to include paths in vscode but I just can't solve my issue.

My project folder's custom libraries is in the following path

```
"/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra"
```

The infra folder is structured as such:

```
>Infra
   >Include
      ... some header files
   >lib1
     >Include
       ... header files
     >src
       ... cpp files
   >lib2
     >Include
       ... header files
     >src
       ... cpp files
```

So, in order to use any of these libraries, I set up the vscode environment

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [ {"name": "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "value": "/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH" }],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
        }
    ]
}
```

**tasks.json**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "label": "C/C++: g++ build active file",
            "command": "/usr/bin/g++",
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
                "-I",
                "/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

**c_cpp_properties.json**

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**",
                "/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra"
            ],
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

and yet, not a single library can be included:

**cpp file**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <libadm.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}



Executing task: /usr/bin/g++ -g /home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra/parser.cpp -o /home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra/parser -I /home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra <

/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra/parser.cpp:2:20: fatal error: libadm.h: No such file or directory
 #include <libadm.h>
```

I tried using slashes but it doesn't change a thing. What drives me crazy is that if I CTRL-click the library it actually shows me the header file of that library, meaning that vscode is correctly linking files togheter.

I also tried using quotes instead of brackets for the include but nothing works

Comment: According to what you've described there are no header files in `/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra`, they are in `/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra/include` and `/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra/lib1/include` and`/home/gdl/DSS2-DEV/infra/lib2/include` so its not surprising it doesn't work.

Comment: @john so there's no way to make the compiler look into the folder recursively and instead I need to pass each and every single path to g++ with "-I"?!

Comment: Yes, g++ needs to see each and every path, the alternative would be to include part of the path in the `#include` directive. E.g. `#include <include/libadm.h>`

Comment: @john as I wrote, adding the full path with slashes doesn't work and now I just added the full path inside the "tasks.json" arguments: one library is found, the other is not. Despite having the same structure

Comment: Well I can't explain that. As I understand it tasks.json is the file you have to edit to control the compilation. Maybe post your updated tasks.json if you can't work it out.

Comment: Have you tried searching for libadm.h? Should it be somewhere in `${workspaceFolder}/**`, wherever that is?

Comment: @rturrado libadm is "lib2". I just put placeholders in my post. All header files and relative source files are stored exactly the same folder-structure wise

Comment: @kn0bbulo as @john said i'd whether add the 3 include directories in the tasks.json file or use something like `#include "Include/lib2/Include/libadm.h". Check for case sensitivity in your paths!